# How do I read exception message from Javascript in IE?

Tags: javascript

I'm throwing an exception in my code. IE9 console reads "Exception thrown and not caught".

Is there a way so that it actually says the message I threw with it? I feel like there should be and I've just been missing it all these years.

Tried both

```
throw( 'Message' )
throw( {message:'Hi'} )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think if IE is telling you that an exception is being *thrown*, but not being *caught*, that's all the info you're going to get here. Exceptions that are thrown are meant to be caught. That way you can take your errors and error messages and do what you want with them, i.e., handle the error accordingly and/or display the error messages in a good place for you or your user to view.

If you want to see uncaught exceptions, use a better js debugger like [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/downloads).